# preg_match denial of service in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, denial-of-service

I am using a form for a input of regular expression itself and then use this regexp in preg_match, so there we dont need validation(maybe only length) but i hear on google "regular expression denial of service" in different programming languages.

There doesn't seem to mention PHP,
**Is it possible in PHP also!?**

**Also should i be considering using regular expression client-side in java web application since the data to get matched aren't really necessary in server-side!??**

Comment: What is your actual question? This just seems like you are ranting to yourself..

Comment: dont you read it until the end, I ASK is it possible in PHP also!? :|

Comment: Perhaps you should format your question better to make it clear. I read until the end and your question did not jump out at me

Comment: Im not used with the specal chars newLine Bold etc, of formatting questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, never trust any data from the client-side to be valid.  You can't even assume that the data came from your website's form or that the user is using a browser to interact with your site.  Thus, you should always do validation on the server-side even if you have some basic validation on the client side (like checking for length).

According to this article PHP is no exception:

http://www.abemiester.com/abemiester/post/RegEx-DOS-attack-Regular-Expressions-Now-you-have-3-problems.aspx

You need to make sure you write your regexes carefully.  This article also mentions "Regex Fuzzer" which is a method of finding problematic regexes.  The link at the top of the article has more information about that.

Edit: Microsoft has built a program to test for vulnerable regexes.  It's available from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20095
I haven't tried it myself, but that might help you find any issues with your regex.